# Create a new syntax highlighting by reusing an existing syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I would like to create a new syntax highlighting files to colorize files with specific suffix (let's say `.cext` extenstion).

The `.cext` files are written with a syntax close to C++ but with some additional keywords and constructs.

Is there a way to create such new syntax highlighting without reinventing the wheel and by stating that the starting point is C++ syntax with some additional rules needed by the extensions used in `.cext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user manual explains how to do this at [`:help 44.9`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_44.txt.html#44.9).

In your new `cext.vim` syntax highlighting file, add the following line to include the Vim runtime's existing C++ highlighting:

```
:runtime! syntax/cpp.vim
```

You can then add/adjust rules to meet your requirements.